# Is there a real-life situation where a simple pointer-to-bool as thread cancellation flag will not effectively cancel a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, cancellation, thread-synchronization

First and foremost, I understand that formally, using a non-`atomic` flag to cancel a thread is very much undefined behaviour in the sense that the language does not specify if this variable will be written to before the thread exits.

At work, this was implemented a long time ago, and most calculation threads check the value of this `bool` throughout their work, as to gracefully cancel whatever it is they're doing. When I first saw this, my first reaction was to change all of this to use a better way (in this case, `QThread::requestInterruption` and `QThread::interruptionRequested` seemed like a viable alternative). A quick search through the code turned up about 800 occurences of this variable/construct throughout the codebase, so I let it go.

When I approached a (senior, in terms of years of experience) colleague, he assured me that although it might indeed be wrong, he had never seen it fail to fulfill its purpose. He argued that the only case it would go wrong is if a (group of) thread(s) is allowed to run and another thread that actually changes this flag never gets allowed to execute untill the other threads are finished. He also argued that in this case, the OS would intervene and fairly distribute runtime across all threads, resulting in perhaps a delay of the cancellation.

Now my question is: is there any real-life situation (preferably on a regular system, based upon x86/ARM, preferably C or C++) where this does indeed fail?

Note I'm not trying to win the argument, as my colleague agrees it is technically incorrect, but I would like to know if it could cause problems and under which circumstances this might occur.

Comment: It's not just the compiler you need be worried about, the extra instruction added for reading/writing std:atomic<*> ensure that the level 1, 2, 3 etc CPU caches are in a consistent state across the CPU(s)/ virtual processors.  Even if the compiler does NOT optimise out the read of the flag in the thread the result read from the cache need not reflect the real value of the flag as the CPU caches will be out of sync.

Comment: This question is incomplete without providing a declaration for the variable(s) you're using across threads.

Comment: @KubaOber there is only a (pointer to) `bool` inside a subclass of a `QThread`.

Comment: Give the declaration - a complete one. Really.

Comment: If your flag is declared literally as `class Foo : public QThread { bool * stop; ... };` then it is perfectly fine for the compiler to assume that it doesn't change outside of the function that uses it. So any tests can be hoisted out of the loop, and then it'll have no effect. But that's silly, all you need is to declare it `volatile bool * stop` and you won't have any issues.

Comment: @Kuba volatile make atomic bool does not - Yoda++.

Comment: @rubenvb In practice, it doesn't have to be atomic. On any sane platform it will work fine, but of course it's not a memory barrier so e.g. on multicore ARMs it might have some pesky side effects.

Comment: @Kuba well that sort of thing ("on any sane platform it will work fine") is exactly what I'm asking about. When does that assertion fail?

Comment: @rubenvb On nothing that you can buy in a store, I don't think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to beat this is to reduce it to a rather trivial example. The compiler will optimize out reading the flag because it is not atomic and being written to by another thread is UB; therefore the flag won't ever get actually *read*.

Your colleague's argument is predicated on the assumption that the compiler will actually *load* the flag when you de-reference the flag. But in fact it has no obligation to do so.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

bool cancelled = false;
bool finished = false;

void thread1() {
    while(!cancelled) {
        std::cout << "Not cancelled";
    }
}
int main() {
    std::thread t(thread1);
    t.detach();
    cancelled = true;
    while(!finished) {}
}
```

To run on coliru, load http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5be139ee34bf0a80, you will need to edit and make a trivial change because the caching is broken for snippets that do not terminate.

Effectively, he's simply betting that the compiler's optimizer will do a poor job, which seems like a truly terrible thing to rely upon.

Comment: In the code, `finished` is not set to true, so `main` definitely will not return... Add `finished = true` in `thread1()`, it runs OK. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b64206934b0689db

Comment: This is a rather non-practical example: nobody would code it that way. `cancelled` should be volatile, and then your code will work, even if it might be technically UB (or perhaps not anymore in C++11).

Answer (score 0):

As can be inferred from Mine's comment, Puppy's code example does not demonstrate the problem. A few minor modifications are necessary.

Firstly, we must add `finished = true;` at the end of `thread1` so that the program even pretends to be able to terminate.

Now, the optimizer isn't able to check every function in every translation unit to be sure that `cancelled` is in fact always `false` when entering `thread1`, so it cannot make the daring optimization to remove the while loop and everything after it. We can fix that by setting `cancelled` to false at the start of `thread1`.

With the previous addition, for fairness, we must also continually set `cancelled` to true in `main`, because otherwise we cannot guarantee that the single assignment in `main` is not scheduled after the initial assignment of in `thread1`.

Edit: Added qualifiers, and synchronous join instead of detachment.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

bool cancelled = false;
bool finished = false;

void thread1() {
    cancelled = false;
    while(!cancelled)
        ;
    finished = true;
}
int main() {
    std::thread t(thread1);
    while(!finished) {
        std::cout << "trying to cancel\n";
        cancelled = true;
    }
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: This example's behavior critically depends on how `cancelled` and `finished` were declared, and you should never wait for a thread to finish something other than by using a memory barrier. `t.detach()` is wrong if you're not using `t.join()` or an atomic load acquire, and a release in the thread.

Comment: @KubaOber the code is complementary to Puppy's example. The flags are global `bool`s with no qualifiers. Obviously, if the flags were declared as `std::atomic<bool>`, then there would be no issue. This example is demonstrating the problem that arises from using a simple non-atomic flag without proper synchronization. Unless I'm mistaken, using `t.join()` would be very wrong if the thread was detached. Anyway, I changed my example to use join instead, to demonstrate that it makes no difference to this problem. I also added volatile qualifiers to demonstrate that they make no difference.

Comment: On second thought, I removed volatile from the example, because that does prevent the optimization. rubenvb didn't say that the flags are volatile, though.

Comment: Strictly `volatile` is not enough in this case, as the compiler may still legitimately perform some optimizations that may break concurrent code. I'm not certain of actually constructing an example, though.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you wait for the threads to finish before using their data, you'll be OK in practice: the memory barriers set by `std::thread::join` or `QThread::wait` will protect you.

Your worry isn't about the `cancelled` variable, as long as it's volatile you're in practice fine. You should worry about reading inconsistent state of the data modified by the threads.